# How can create a random code

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I want a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 code does when you press the button opens the next page randomly (from between the pages in the program) ??

thanks

Comment: Did you even try *at all*?

Comment: what are you talking??

Comment: @IbrahimTornado - What Jashaszun was probably trying to ask is what did you try? Just posting this question doesn't show any effort on your behalf. We're not a code writing service. You should come here with your code ready to post and we can help you fix your code.

Comment: sorry, but I try code in this case but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int randomNumber;

randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, n + 1);

switch(randomNumber)
{
   case 1: ShowPage1();
           break;
   case 2: ShowPage2();
           break;
   case 3: ShowPage3();
           break;
   ...
   case n: ShowPageN();
             break;
}
```

Comment: `.Next(1,3)` only returns either `1` or `2`. The `3` is an exclusive upper bound.

Comment: Just used 3 as an example. `.Next(1, n)` where n => number of pages.

Comment: You're not following. If you do `.Next(1, n)` then you get a random number from the range of `{ 1, 2, ..., n - 1 }` - you never get `n`. It's an **exclusive** upper bound.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Sorry! Got it now. Have updated the answer.